# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button')

Tags: c#

i have a linked button in my a datalist with value of datatype int onclick it is supposed to display all details in a datalist list on another page based on the id link button chosen.

But i am having  this error in my codes:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_m5vpwb3j.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button')

Comment: Please add your code to your question.  Check out [ask] for details.

Answer (score 2):

Both a [`LinkButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and a [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) are a subclass of [`WebControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx). However, they are siblings in the type hierarchy, so you cannot cast one into the other. They are *not* compatible to each other.

So what you are doing simply doesn’t work, you will have to look for another way to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: Which way do you suggest this will work using asp.net

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, so that’s kind of difficult to say. But you can always handle both button types individually.

Comment: i have a datagrid view consisting of an id, name and age. i want the name to be a link to another page and display all the information based on the name clicked in another gridview in a different page

Comment: Thanks! I was having this problem when I tried to cast LinkButton to Button